# Difficulty syncing Ubuntu with satellite-sync

Tags: ubuntu

We have a fairly complex setup in that our production environment is not able to connect to the internet.
To aid in lifecycle, I am using Spacewalk server in our test environment with a cloned channel by date for patching release, and that channel gets sync'ed to the spacewalk server in production.

This is working perfectly for Oracle Linux and CentOS, but I am having some issues getting Ubuntu Precise to work the same way.

Here an extract of the procedure:
On the test Spacewalk, I sync from the official mirror:
`spacewalk-debian-sync.pl --username xxxx --password 'xxxx' --channel 'precise-security' --url 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/main/binary-amd64/'`

This channel is then cloned to the point in time patching starts:
--snip from conf file--

```
"precise-security": {
  "label": "pit_precise_security",
  "name": "Point In Time Repo Security x86_64",
  "summary": "Contains a point in time repo",
  "description": "Security Repo For Precise Security",
  "parent": "pit_ubuntu_12.04"
},
```

-- snip --
Then executed: `spacewalk-clone-by-date -c /opt/scripts/clone_precise_to_st.conf -d $DATE`

This is working fine and the test servers happily patch off the cloned channel.

On the production side I run this:
`satellite-sync --iss-parent=tst-spacewalk.ics.dmz --ca-cert="/usr/share/rhn/RHN-ORG-TRUSTED-SSL-CERT" -c pit_precise_security`

This fails with:

```
IntegrityError: null value in column "label" violates not-null constraint 
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (30, null, 2015-08-10 16:35:26.658707+12, N, null).
```

Yet the same config works for the other os's.
Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: I might have not phrased the question correctly then as it is purely a inter satellite sync problem. The fact that it is Ubuntu packages should be purely semantical unless I am missing something. All packages are imported fine into the first satellite, cloned fine, just the iss fails with a spacewalk postgres error. So the sync between two satellites are failing.

Comment: Hoping other knowledgeable people are not thrown off by the initial response. None if these processes have anything to do with Ubuntu. The servers are all running CentOS, no Ubuntu servers were used in the generation of this issue. 

Comment: OK, I've removed the close vote - you've argued your case. I wouldn't worry too much about the vote - a close vote has never stopped me from responding to a question. Good luck with your search for an answer.